# Python: How to convert string entries with only numeric components in a column to integer?

Tags: python, string, pandas, integer

I have a data frame with string type columns that have both character and numeric entries.

Below is an example df:

```
A        B
101a5    12222
11111    e2edw2
22222    33333
asxaa    0045
```

I want to turn the entries with only numeric values from string into integer, but keep the rest as string.

What would be the best approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because you have mixed types in one column you will get `object` dtype anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
def func(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x

df = df.applymap(func)

print(df.applymap(type))
```

Output:

```
               A              B
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'int'>
1  <class 'int'>  <class 'str'>
2  <class 'int'>  <class 'int'>
3  <class 'str'>  <class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just convert the dataframe to integers and ignore any resulting errors which would return the original string instead.

Can't get much simpler...

```
df.astype(int, errors='ignore')

# pandas 1.0.0
>>> df.astype(int, errors='ignore').applymap(type)
               A              B
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'int'>
1  <class 'int'>  <class 'str'>
2  <class 'int'>  <class 'int'>
3  <class 'str'>  <class 'int'>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked!